# Using indexed views to encapsulate the complexity of larger queries is ok for performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, indexed-view

i am creating a complex querying system based on a "framework of views".

In this way writing high level queries is very easy.

Currently the performance is bad (comparing to what I could achieve by not using views), but using indexed views is a solution? If I create a clustered index only for the fields where I need to do joins against is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> > "framework of views"

If you are in early stages of this task then i would encourage you to drop this idea of "framework of views". While its true that it hides alot of complexity to some extent only at the cost of performance. And if you have nested views, you will have lot of problems going forward. Go to any SQL Server forums and look for nested views performance issues and you will see the pain.

One of the problems is some predicates are NOT pushed down correctly and efficiently as it would have been on the actual tables.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/08/14/select-from-a-view-slower-than-equivalent-select-from-the-base-table.aspx

Indexed views solve some problems effectively but not in all cases and comes with lot of restrictions. If the readwrite ratio is less then you will have more performance issues. I have used indexed views effectively in some cases to drop the IO significantly [tens of thousands logical IOs to single digit IOs] but those had high read to write ratio.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx

Comment: so you suggest to stick with very large queries?

Comment: yes. don't sacrifice performance at the cost of looking at large queries. Good formatting will take you a long way here.